# What income bracket(s) are eligible for the GST/HST credit in Ontario?

Tags: canada, hst, ontario, gst, gst-credit

As per the information on [CRA website](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/gsthst/fq_qlfyng-eng.html#q1), the eligibility for GST/HST credit is met if any one of the below are true:

> - You are 19 years of age or older before the month in which we make a quarterly payment;
> - You have (or previously had) a spouse or common-law partner; or
> - You are (or previously were) a parent and live (or previously lived) with your child.

For me, the first one is true, but last year I remember getting a note from CRA that I do not qualify for the credit because I am not in the proper income bracket. I am confused because the website does not mention the proper income bracket.

What income bracket(s) are eligible for the GST/HST credit in Ontario?

Comment: How mush for single parent with one child

Answer (score 3):

The [CRA's GST/HST information page](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/gsthstcredit/) links to a page titled ["Income Levels"](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/gsthst/gstc_ncms-eng.html), which states:

> If your family net income amount is equal to or exceeds the amount indicated in the table below, you will not be entitled to a GST/HST credit payment.

For a single person, you aren't eligible for the credit if your income exceeds **$42,641**, per the table in the second link. Other family structures have different income limits:

```
Single person                                       $42,641
Single parent with one child                        $47,941
Single parent with two children                     $50,721
Single parent with three children                   $53,501
Single parent with four children                    $56,281
Married/common-law couple with no children          $45,161
Married/common-law couple with one child            $47,941
Married/common-law couple with two children         $50,721
Married/common-law couple with three children       $53,501
Married/common-law couple with four children        $56,281
```

Comment: For posterity, note that these numbers are inflation adjusted and updated annually, at the link provided.

Answer (score -1):

It now: (for 2015 filing) - For a single person, you aren't eligible for the credit if your income exceeds $44,346

This info is from Revenue Canada website.